# Inserting a ListView in an Activity

Tags: android, listview, exception

I have a problem to insert a ListView into an Activity. I just inserted a List with extending from ListActivity. This just works fine. I also know how to forward to another Activity by selecting a row. But this time it doesn't work. I just tried to debug everything by going from line to line and always check the error messages from LogCat. I also loo. But now i don't know what to. Everything seems to be on the right place.

Through logging the elements from the database (in the second block), i found out that the last element is empty. Because of that i reduced the for-loop by one. So the whole method "initVars()" works, till it gets to the end of it, returns to the "onCreate" block again and stops working. I just copy the error message, maybe theres somebody who knows what it means.

```
public class ActivityDetail extends Activity {

    TextView tvDefinition, tvDurationSingle, tvDurationMultiplied, tvSubunits;
    ListView lvExecution;
    String executions[];
    ArrayList<Execution> allExecutionsFromDatabase;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    UserInformation userInfo = UserInformation.getInstance();
    MyFramework myFramework;

    // Extras from intent
    String definition;
    int activityId, durationSingle, durationMultiplied, subunits;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitydetail);

    initVars();

}

private void initVars() {

    myFramework = new MyFramework();

    // load extras into variables
    definition = myFramework.getExtrasString("activitiyDefinition",
            getIntent().getExtras());
    activityId = myFramework.getExtrasInt("activityId", getIntent()
            .getExtras());
    durationSingle = myFramework.getExtrasInt("activityDuration",
            getIntent().getExtras());
    subunits = myFramework.getExtrasInt("activitySubunits", getIntent()
            .getExtras());
    durationMultiplied = durationSingle * subunits;

    // init ui elements
    tvDefinition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvActDetailDefinition);
    tvDurationSingle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvActDetailDurationSingle);
    tvDurationMultiplied = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvActDetailDurationMultiplied);
    tvSubunits = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvActDetailSubunits);
    lvExecution = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvActDetail);

    // get executions from db
    ActivityDB entries = new ActivityDB(this);
    entries.open();
    allExecutionsFromDatabase = entries.getSpecificExecutions(
            userInfo.getUserId(), activityId);
    entries.close();
```

---

```
    // set list array to same size as allExecutionsFromDatabase
    executions = new String[allExecutionsFromDatabase.size()];

    // insert definition of each execution in executions for listview
    for (int i = 0; i < allExecutionsFromDatabase.size() - 1; i++) {
        Execution e = new Execution();
        e = allExecutionsFromDatabase.get(i);
        executions[i] = e.getTimestamp();
        Log.e("DEFINITION", "" + e.getTimestamp());
    }
```

---

```
    // init array adapter
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ActivityDetail.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, executions);

    // add adapter and onClickListener to listview
    lvExecution.setAdapter(adapter);

    lvExecution.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String a = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            if (a == "Foo")
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Foobar! xD",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

LOCCAT

```
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at  android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-08 23:55:25.361: E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 00:00:25.431: I/Process(23627): Sending signal. PID: 23627 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I have no idea where to start looking. Part of code are missing, so I don't know where what belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not populate whole `executions` array:

```
executions = new String[allExecutionsFromDatabase.size()];
```

as you iterate only untill

```
for (int i = 0; i < allExecutionsFromDatabase.size() - 1; i++) {
```

the last index entry in `executions` remains null.

This is on first glimpse - not sure if it is a reason for null pointer exc and the only reason too :).

Comment: I just mentioned at the beginning of my post, that i logged all activities that will be received from the database. i can't imagine why theres one more entry because i looked at the db in the shell and there haven't been an undefined position. So i just reduced it, because i thought it might cause the error because of an undefined activity.

Comment: ok, you've solved the problem. I reduced the array size i received from the database and so there was an empty too much inside the executions array, which represents the elements of the list. Thank you very much. Looking for hours at the same code you loose any motivation.